# Custom taxonomy isn't showing on custom post list (I'm trying to literally copy a working code)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with a custom WP theme and trying to create a custom post type with custom taxonomy on it. I'm tried to copy and modify an another code that is already in use on this code (obviously modifying some parts) but isn't work.

My question is what I'm doing wrong and how can I make this work properly.

The working code shows a custom post type on the admin panel with his taxonomies. Also, I can change it using the Advanced Custom Field. Mine custom post type can't.

- Print of working custom post type
  https://i.ibb.co/YhWsWV5/Screen-Shot-2019-06-17-at-14-25-53.png
- Print of my custom post type
  https://i.ibb.co/LxM557G/Screen-Shot-2019-06-17-at-14-52-01.png

My code

```php
function cpt_cursos_rop() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => 'Cursos ROP',
        'singular_name'         => 'Curso ROP',
        'menu_name'             => 'Cursos ROP',
        'name_admin_bar'        => 'Cursos ROP',
        'archives'              => 'Arquivo de Cursos',
        'attributes'            => 'Atributos do Curso',
        'parent_item_colon'     => 'Curso Pai:',
        'all_items'             => 'Todos os Cursos',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Adicionar Novo Curso',
        'add_new'               => 'Adicionar Novo',
        'new_item'              => 'Novo Curso',
        'edit_item'             => 'Editar Curso',
        'update_item'           => 'Atualizar Curso',
        'view_item'             => 'Ver Curso',
        'view_items'            => 'Ver Cursos',
        'search_items'          => 'Procurar Curso',
        'not_found'             => 'Nada Encontrado',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'Nada Encontrado na Lixeira',
        'featured_image'        => 'Imagem Destacada',
        'set_featured_image'    => 'Definir imagem destacada',
        'remove_featured_image' => 'Remover imagem destacada',
        'use_featured_image'    => 'Utilizar como imagem destacada',
        'insert_into_item'      => 'Inserir no Curso',
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => 'Enviado para este Curso',
        'items_list'            => 'Lista de Cursos',
        'items_list_navigation' => 'Navegação da lista de Cursos',
        'filter_items_list'     => 'Filtrar lista de Cursos',
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                => 'curso-rop',
        'with_front'          => true,
        'pages'               => true,
        'feeds'               => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'description'           => 'Registros de Cursos',
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'categoria_especialidades_rop', 'categoria_tipos_rop' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-exerpt-view',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
        'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
        'show_in_rest'          => false,
    );

    register_post_type( 'CursosROP', $args );


    //TAXONOMIA - ESPECIALIDADES
    $labels_especialidades = array(
        'name'                       => 'Especialidades',
        'singular_name'              => 'Especialidade',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Especialidades',
        'all_items'                  => 'Todas as Especialidades',
        'parent_item'                => 'Especialidade Mãe',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Especialidade Mãe:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'Novo nome de Especialidade',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Adicionar Nova Especialidade',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Editar Especialidade',
        'update_item'                => 'Atualizar Especialidade',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separe as especialidades com virgulas',
        'search_items'               => 'Buscar Especialidades',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Adicionar ou remover Especialidades',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Escolher dentre as Especialidades mais utilizadas',
        'not_found'                  => 'Nada Localizado',
    );
    $rewrite_especialidades = array(
        'slug'                       => 'especialidades',
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
    );
    $args_especialidades = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels_especialidades,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite_especialidades,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'categoria_rop', 'curso-rop', $args_especialidades );

    //TAXONOMIA - TIPO
    $labels_tipos = array(
        'name'                       => 'Tipos',
        'singular_name'              => 'Tipo',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Tipos',
        'all_items'                  => 'Todas os Tipos',
        'parent_item'                => 'Tipo Mãe',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Tipo Mãe:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'Novo nome de Tipo',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Adicionar Novo Tipo',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Editar Tipo',
        'update_item'                => 'Atualizar Tipo',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separe os tipos com virgulas',
        'search_items'               => 'Buscar Tipos',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Adicionar ou remover Tipo',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Escolher dentreos Tipos mais utilizados',
        'not_found'                  => 'Nada Localizado',
    );
    $rewrite_tipos = array(
        'slug'                       => 'tipos',
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
    );
    $args_tipos = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels_tipos,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite_tipos,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'categoria_tipos_rop', 'cursosROP', $args_tipos );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_cursos_rop', 0 );
```

The working code (for reference)

```php
function cpt_cursos() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => 'Cursos',
        'singular_name'         => 'Curso',
        'menu_name'             => 'Cursos',
        'name_admin_bar'        => 'Cursos',
        'archives'              => 'Arquivo de Cursos',
        'attributes'            => 'Atributos do Curso',
        'parent_item_colon'     => 'Curso Pai:',
        'all_items'             => 'Todos os Cursos',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Adicionar Novo Curso',
        'add_new'               => 'Adicionar Novo',
        'new_item'              => 'Novo Curso',
        'edit_item'             => 'Editar Curso',
        'update_item'           => 'Atualizar Curso',
        'view_item'             => 'Ver Curso',
        'view_items'            => 'Ver Cursos',
        'search_items'          => 'Procurar Curso',
        'not_found'             => 'Nada Encontrado',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'Nada Encontrado na Lixeira',
        'featured_image'        => 'Imagem Destacada',
        'set_featured_image'    => 'Definir imagem destacada',
        'remove_featured_image' => 'Remover imagem destacada',
        'use_featured_image'    => 'Utilizar como imagem destacada',
        'insert_into_item'      => 'Inserir no Curso',
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => 'Enviado para este Curso',
        'items_list'            => 'Lista de Cursos',
        'items_list_navigation' => 'Navegação da lista de Cursos',
        'filter_items_list'     => 'Filtrar lista de Cursos',
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                => 'curso',
        'with_front'          => true,
        'pages'               => true,
        'feeds'               => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'description'           => 'Registros de Cursos',
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'categoria_especialidades', 'categoria_tipos' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-exerpt-view',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,       
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
        'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
        'show_in_rest'          => false,
    );

    register_post_type( 'Cursos', $args );


    //TAXONOMIA - ESPECIALIDADES
    $labels_especialidades = array(
        'name'                       => 'Especialidades',
        'singular_name'              => 'Especialidade',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Especialidades',
        'all_items'                  => 'Todas as Especialidades',
        'parent_item'                => 'Especialidade Mãe',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Especialidade Mãe:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'Novo nome de Especialidade',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Adicionar Nova Especialidade',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Editar Especialidade',
        'update_item'                => 'Atualizar Especialidade',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separe as especialidades com virgulas',
        'search_items'               => 'Buscar Especialidades',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Adicionar ou remover Especialidades',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Escolher dentre as Especialidades mais utilizadas',
        'not_found'                  => 'Nada Localizado',
    );
    $rewrite_especialidades = array(
        'slug'                       => 'especialidades',
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
    );
    $args_especialidades = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels_especialidades,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite_especialidades,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'categoria_especialidades', 'cursos', $args_especialidades );

    //TAXONOMIA - TIPO
    $labels_tipos = array(
        'name'                       => 'Tipos',
        'singular_name'              => 'Tipo',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Tipos',
        'all_items'                  => 'Todas os Tipos',
        'parent_item'                => 'Tipo Mãe',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Tipo Mãe:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'Novo nome de Tipo',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Adicionar Novo Tipo',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Editar Tipo',
        'update_item'                => 'Atualizar Tipo',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separe os tipos com virgulas',
        'search_items'               => 'Buscar Tipos',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Adicionar ou remover Tipo',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Escolher dentreos Tipos mais utilizados',
        'not_found'                  => 'Nada Localizado',
    );
    $rewrite_tipos = array(
        'slug'                       => 'tipos',
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
    );
    $args_tipos = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels_tipos,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite_tipos,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'categoria_tipos', 'cursos', $args_tipos );

}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_cursos', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was you weren't calling the correct 'especialidades' which was 'categoria_rop' and both taxonomies were being registered to the wrong post type name it needed to be 'curso-rop' not 'curso-rop' and 'cursosROP' as you had it.

See below:

```
function cpt_cursos_rop() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => 'Cursos ROP',
        'singular_name'         => 'Curso ROP',
        'menu_name'             => 'Cursos ROP',
        'name_admin_bar'        => 'Cursos ROP',
        'archives'              => 'Arquivo de Cursos',
        'attributes'            => 'Atributos do Curso',
        'parent_item_colon'     => 'Curso Pai:',
        'all_items'             => 'Todos os Cursos',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Adicionar Novo Curso',
        'add_new'               => 'Adicionar Novo',
        'new_item'              => 'Novo Curso',
        'edit_item'             => 'Editar Curso',
        'update_item'           => 'Atualizar Curso',
        'view_item'             => 'Ver Curso',
        'view_items'            => 'Ver Cursos',
        'search_items'          => 'Procurar Curso',
        'not_found'             => 'Nada Encontrado',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'Nada Encontrado na Lixeira',
        'featured_image'        => 'Imagem Destacada',
        'set_featured_image'    => 'Definir imagem destacada',
        'remove_featured_image' => 'Remover imagem destacada',
        'use_featured_image'    => 'Utilizar como imagem destacada',
        'insert_into_item'      => 'Inserir no Curso',
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => 'Enviado para este Curso',
        'items_list'            => 'Lista de Cursos',
        'items_list_navigation' => 'Navegação da lista de Cursos',
        'filter_items_list'     => 'Filtrar lista de Cursos',
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                => 'curso-rop',
        'with_front'          => true,
        'pages'               => true,
        'feeds'               => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'description'           => 'Registros de Cursos',
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'categoria_rop', 'categoria_tipos_rop' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-exerpt-view',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
        'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
        'show_in_rest'          => false,
    );

    register_post_type( 'CursosROP', $args );


    //TAXONOMIA - ESPECIALIDADES
    $labels_especialidades = array(
        'name'                       => 'Especialidades',
        'singular_name'              => 'Especialidade',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Especialidades',
        'all_items'                  => 'Todas as Especialidades',
        'parent_item'                => 'Especialidade Mãe',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Especialidade Mãe:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'Novo nome de Especialidade',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Adicionar Nova Especialidade',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Editar Especialidade',
        'update_item'                => 'Atualizar Especialidade',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separe as especialidades com virgulas',
        'search_items'               => 'Buscar Especialidades',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Adicionar ou remover Especialidades',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Escolher dentre as Especialidades mais utilizadas',
        'not_found'                  => 'Nada Localizado',
    );
    $rewrite_especialidades = array(
        'slug'                       => 'especialidades',
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
    );
    $args_especialidades = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels_especialidades,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite_especialidades,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'categoria_rop', 'cursosrop', $args_especialidades );

    //TAXONOMIA - TIPO
    $labels_tipos = array(
        'name'                       => 'Tipos',
        'singular_name'              => 'Tipo',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Tipos',
        'all_items'                  => 'Todas os Tipos',
        'parent_item'                => 'Tipo Mãe',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Tipo Mãe:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'Novo nome de Tipo',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Adicionar Novo Tipo',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Editar Tipo',
        'update_item'                => 'Atualizar Tipo',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separe os tipos com virgulas',
        'search_items'               => 'Buscar Tipos',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Adicionar ou remover Tipo',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Escolher dentreos Tipos mais utilizados',
        'not_found'                  => 'Nada Localizado',
    );
    $rewrite_tipos = array(
        'slug'                       => 'tipos',
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
    );
    $args_tipos = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels_tipos,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite_tipos,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'categoria_tipos_rop', 'cursosrop', $args_tipos );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_cursos_rop', 0 );
```